# Position sticky with columns of different width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make HTML and CSS combination to achive columns that stick to each other. The fiddle shows everthing i want to achive but i had to put "left:" parameter manualy. Can i write something in JS or in CSS so i won't have to put this parameter manualy everytime i use other width of column?

Idea:
3 columns are sticky so: first one is left: 0 and second is left: x and third is left: y.
Is there a way to make them dynamic so it will work with random x and y.

```
td,
th {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 align-self: flex-start;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 100;
}
.ddd {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 align-self: flex-start;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 101;
}
.dddd {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 align-self: flex-start;
 left: 90px;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 101;
}
.ddddd {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 align-self: flex-start;
 left: 190px;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 101;
}

<table style="width:2000px" border="1">
<tr  >
<th  style="width:90px" class="sticky-col">Firstname</th>
<th style="width:100px" class="sticky-to-left-elem">Lastname</th>
<th style="width:140px">Age</th>
<td style="width:40px">Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr  >
<td  style="width:90px" class="sticky-col">Jill</td>
<td  style="width:100px" class="sticky-to-left-elem">Smith</td>
<td style="width:140px">50</td>
<td style="width:40px">Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr  >
<td  style="width:90px" class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
<td style="width:100px" class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
<td style="width:140px">94</td>
<td style="width:40px">Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:90px" class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
<td style="width:100px" class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
<td style="width:140px">94</td>
<td style="width:40px">Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  style="width:90px" class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
<td style="width:100px" class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
<td style="width:140px">94</td>
<td style="width:40px">Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  style="width:90px" class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
<td  style="width:100px" class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
<td style="width:140px">94</td>
<td style="width:40px">Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
</tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:90px" class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
<td  style="width:100px" class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
<td style="width:140px">94</td>
<td style="width:40px">Eve</td>
<td>Jackson</td>
<td>94</td>
</tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e0xc69dg/

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. Do you mean `border-collapse: collapse`? If so, you can add `table {border-collapse: collapse;}` to your code

Comment: I am trying to make collumns stick to each other as i move horizontaly without knowing what width will they have.

Answer (score 0):

use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.container.full-width .item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.container.auto-width .item {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.item {
  color: white;
}

.item-1 {
  background: red;
}

.item-2 {
  background: purple;
}

.item-3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container full-width">
  <div class="item item-1">
    row 1 with very loooooooooong text
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    row 2 with short text
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    row 3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container auto-width">
  <div class="item item-1">
    row 1 with very loooooooooong text
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    row 2 with short text
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">
    row 3
  </div>
</div>
```